# Centos 7 errors on each command

Tags: shell, centos7

Abruptedly when I execute any command on my Centros 7 shell I receive errors hampering their executions. Errors are of the kind:

```
$ ls
-bash: /usr/bin/ls: Input/output error
$ df
-bash: df: command not found
$ top
-bash: /usr/bin/top: Input/output error
```

I tried rebotting the machine to no avail and no service like fsftp or http work. Please help me as soon as possible as that is the main server of my backoffice.

Comment: Have you tried googling? [This](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=930991) is literally the first thing that comes up for me when I type "bash input output error". According to the answers there, you need to post a lot more info if you want exact details on how your disk crashed.

Comment: Even dmesg and mount give error:
-bash: /usr/bin/dmesg: Input/output error
$ mount
-bash: /usr/bin/mount: Input/output error

Comment: If the issue is a disk failure I would need to reinstall everything as of course I have no backup of the filesystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue on the provider, Crissic, one notified and acknowledged the issue it took a day to fix it.

Comment: What do you mean issue on the provider?